# SQL Query to Scan for a String of text in a Table

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to implement an SQL code in order to scan a table of a database for a specific string of text that will alter with each query search.
For example, in the first search variable1 = 'cat'
The query Search for 'cat' will be performed.
If variable1 exists in the table proceed to the next variable value (changes dynamically in my Java stand alone app)
Now lets say that the variable1 = 'dog' The query result is negative (this string is NOT in the DB)
In this case make some processing and store this value in the table.

...and so on with all the values I need to search in the table!

The SQL code will be implemented in eclipse with the rest of my java code.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: `select FieldName from TableName where FieldName like '%Variable%' limit 1;`

Comment: I need to update the table of my DB that stores Last Names. So if I get a new Last name I must first check if it already exists. If it does there will be no processing if there is no entry with this Last Name, process in a way  and store this Last Name in the table of the database

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Oracle pl/sql)

```
insert into pets_table (variable1_col) values ('cat') 
where not exists (select * from pets_table where upper(variable1_col)='CAT')

insert into pets_table (variable1_col) values ('dog') 
where not exists (select * from pets_table where upper(variable1_col)='DOG')
```

Comment: Good database design would reduce the amount of programming required. Make the column containing Variable1 unique, e.g. by adding an index. Then you can insert a new record without worrying if you're adding a duplicate.